# Rtf presentation does not appear in presentations dropdown

Tags: eclipse, rtf, richtext

I installed RMF from the eclipse site : [eclipse.org/rmf](http://download.eclipse.org/rmf/updates/releases)
they'r all up to date.

I want to use rich text in a field. In order to add rtf presentation, I installed ProR Essentials from [formalmind](http://update.formalmind.com/essentials) respect to [this blog page](http://formalmind.com/de/blog/rich-text-support-pror)

I could not install Rich text. An error below comes up:

> Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could not be found.
>     Software being installed: Rich Text: Show and edit XHTML formatted, as they are. 1.0.0.201503131109 (com.formalmind.rmf.reqif10.pror.presentation.rtf.feature.feature.group 1.0.0.201503131109)
>     Missing requirement: ProR Xhtml Rtf Presentation 1.0.0.201503131109 (com.formalmind.rmf.reqif10.pror.presentation.rtf 1.0.0.201503131109) requires 'bundle org.eclipse.fx.javafx 2.2.0' but it could not be found
>     Cannot satisfy dependency:
>       From: Rich Text: Show and edit XHTML formatted, as they are. 1.0.0.201503131109 (com.formalmind.rmf.reqif10.pror.presentation.rtf.feature.feature.group 1.0.0.201503131109)
>       To: com.formalmind.rmf.reqif10.pror.presentation.rtf [1.0.0.201503131109]

Answer (score 0):

The Handbook contains a chapter on installation:

http://formalmind.com/handbook?page=sect0061.html

Installation is tricky, as JavaFX is used. The steps differ, depending on your Eclipse base installation (3 or 4).